# Add width and height attr's to images and or css

Tags: xhtml, height, width, css

I'm working with wordpress and have been removing the width and height attr's when adding images as they are added automatically, however I have been sizing the images via stylesheet:

```
   .foo img {
        max-width:500px;
        width:100%;
    }
```

After doing a little reading it seems the inline attr's help with page loading times so I was wondering:

- Should I use one or the other or both?
- Will the inline attr override the css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should be added inline to help with page loading times, as you mentioned. Inline styles will win against external style sheets, but style sheets will override `height` and `width` attributes.

In other words, `<img height='300' width='300'>` can be overridden in an external style sheet, but not `<img style='height:300;width:300'>`.

Comment: Firstly, the style properties need units. `300px`. Secondly, note that one shouldn't use the attributes any more, as they are obsolete.

Comment: You're right about the missing `px` units. I suppose it was a momentary lapse of memory. However, you are mistaken about the `height` and `width` attributes. They are very much alive and well. `align`, `border`, `hspace` and `vspace` are no longer supported, but height and width are still supported in HTML5.

Comment: My apologies. I find it harder and harder to keep track of which elements and attributes are deprecated or un-deprecated. In this case I was pretty sure I was right though, so I didn't bother to look it up. Oh well.

Comment: I see there is a difference between the HTML5 definition and the HTML4.01 one though: in HTML5, width and height can only be a number in pixels. In HTML4.01, they could also be percentages. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the external sheet if you want all images class foo width the same attributes. The width pixels determine the resolution, the width percentage determines the stretch. Inline will override the external sheet.

Answer (score 0):

External style sheets are used to organize your design and can be cascaded. The advantage of using external style sheets is that you can make changes to one or more independent style sheet files without having to modify inline attributes in the main markup. In this way, you can easily change style properties.

You can use inline styling that will override style sheet properties in most cases but the syntax and format should be correct.

It really depends on what you want to do but I usually prefer external styling as this allows a designer to design (via external style sheets) independent of the developer.

Please refer to http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: The information on the page you link to is incorrect; the author doesn't fully understand how the cascade works. Maybe it's best to remove this link.